# VS Code Integrated Terminal does not recognize mapped keys in Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-events, wayland

I have Ubuntu22 with Wayland and VS Code v. 1.84.2.
I have mapped certain keys with the keyd tool (https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd, you can read more about my keyd configuration in https://www.karimarttila.fi/keyboard/2023/11/16/linux-keyboard-configuration-with-keyd.html). VS Code editor area (as every other editor and Terminator terminal etc in my Ubuntu22) uses the keyd configuration (e.g. arrow keys are capslock+i/j/k/l). But VS Code Integrated Terminal does not recognize these key mappings.

I have googled quite a bit for this issue but not find any solution to my problem. I tried to add similar key mappings for the VS Code Integrated Terminal in VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts, but my capslock or altgr key that I use with i/j/k/l as arrow keys are not recognized by VS Code (VS Code says: "unknown").

Comment: Just found web page:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues

I tried, what happens in the VS Code editor area with "Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting", when I use capslock+i (which should be arrowUp)
=>

Comment: : / Soft dispatching keyboard event
: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: AltRight, keyCode: 225, key: AltGraph
: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: AltRight, keyCode: 0 ('unknown')
: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control

Comment: : | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
KeybindingService]: \ From 22 keybinding entries, matched emacs.cursorUp, when: editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible, source: user extension lfs.vscode-emacs-friendly.

Comment: : / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: ArrowUp, keyCode: 38, key: ArrowUp
: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: ArrowUp, keyCode: 16 ('UpArrow')
: \ From 22 keybinding entries, matched emacs.cursorUp, when: editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible, source: user extension lfs.vscode-emacs-friendly.
: + Invoking command emacs.cursorUp.

Comment: (I added the log events in three separate comments above, because the Stackoverflow UI complained that the comment is too long when I tried to copy-paste the logs into one comment)

Comment: I am using: Settings: / Keyboard: Dispatch = keyCode

Comment: Please always [edit] further info into your question post instead of hiding it in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.